# How to refactor a legacy table with over 30 columns

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, normalization, denormalization

There is a `table`, `WIDE` (anonymous due to NDA), in a legacy project with *Mysql* database. The amount of fields in table `A` has already grown to 30+ since the recent 5 years even though there is no *redundancy* (at least it can be assumed so).

As a result, it is way difficult to browse and query the data in the table.

**Question: How to refactor such table with that many fields?**

As a Java coder, I am thinking of categorizing and splitting those 30+ fields into 3 or more smaller tables, then `join` them if all those fields are needed in the *business logic*. For instance,

Before splitting the table into several smaller tables, there is a query like:

`select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N from WIDE`

Whereas after the splitting, the equivalent query will involve `join`, like

```
select p.A, p.B, p.C, s.D, s.E, s.F, t.G, t.H, t.I, t.J, t.K, t.L, t.M, t.N from PRIM p left join SEC s on ... left join THIRD t on ...`
```

But is such joining affecting the performance even though the separated smaller tables are on a *one-to-one* base?

Comment: Normalize the table, then create a conversion process to copy the old table into the new tables.  Identify all the places in existing, code that have to be modified to read / update the new tables.  Figure out how to modify all the code without disruptions.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks a lot first for the fast comment. As mentioned in the question, the table does not have redundancy, after the normalization copy old table data into the new table would be kinda trivial. But **what about the performance of the `join` mentioned in the question?**

Comment: **What about the performance of the join mentioned in the question?**  Create the new tables, load them, and measure the join performance.  Perhaps try new indexes and measure some more.  Measure, measure, measure.

Comment: Does one column have lots of the same value?  The is what Gilbert is suggesting needs normalizing.  Meanwhile, elaborate on "way difficult to browse".

Comment: If, say, there are columns (address1, address2, city, province, country, postalcode), move that set into a `Locations` table, leaving behind an id to JOIN on.  That is, sometimes it "makes sense" to split up a table.  Some browsing would not care about the locations; some other browsing might simply want to know how many are in each country.